# Cannot convert argument - Template Error

Tags: c++, c++11, reflection, visitor-pattern

I try to implement visitor pattern with templates.

My [code](https://ideone.com/t4nfq0) is:

```
struct some_class
{
    char field1;
    bool field2;

    some_class()
        : field1('a')
        , field2(0)
    {
    }
};

struct unnamed_lambda
{
    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T x) const { return x + 1; }
};

struct unnamed_lambda2
{
    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T x) const { return x + 2; }
};


template<class processor>
void reflect(processor & p, some_class& sc)
{
    reflect(p, sc.field1, "field1");
    reflect(p, sc.field2, "field2");
}

template<class t>
void reflect(unnamed_lambda & p, t& val, string str)
{
    cout << val << endl;
}

void print_helper()
{
    unnamed_lambda lambda = unnamed_lambda{};
    some_class sc;

    reflect(lambda, sc);
}

template<class t>
void reflect2(unnamed_lambda2 & p, t& val, string str)
{
    cout << val + 1 << endl;
}

void print_helper2()
{
    unnamed_lambda2 lambda = unnamed_lambda2{};
    some_class sc;

    reflect(lambda, sc);
}

int main() 
{
    print_helper();
    print_helper2();

    return 0;
}
```

I want to have some class that defines traversal order of its fields. In my case, it is a `void reflect(processor & p, some_class& sc)` function. In addition, I want to have a set of actions on this class. In my case, It is `print_helper` and `print_helper2`.

In order to correlate the operation and the desired action, I create two dumb structure: `unnamed_lambda` and `unnamed_lambda2`. These structures do nothing. It is a workaround.

Why do this code smell so bad? There is a reason. The signature function `void reflect(processor & p, some_class& sc)` is fixed.

In other words, I can do everything except change the signature of this function and its implementation. More I can not change the `some_class` class.

I got confused. I'll be glad for any help on my question.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Barry, how to implement visitor pattern in case of fixed `reflect` function signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the intermediate steps. Your visitor should just visit:

```
template<class processor>
void reflect(processor & p, some_class& sc)
{
    p(sc.field1, "field1");
    p(sc.field2, "field2");
}
```

A visitor might be:

```
struct visitor {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& field, const std::string& name) {
        std::cout << "value of '" << name << "' = " << field << '\n'; 
    }
};

some_class sc;
visitor v;
reflect(v, sc);
```

Comment: I am sorry, but You change implementation of `reflect`. This is an external code for me. I can not change the class `some_class` and the function `void reflect(processor & p, some_class& sc)`.

Comment: Then write `template <typename V, typename F>
void reflect(V& v, F& field, const string& name) { v(field, name); }`